# How can I properly input features with multiple values in machine learning using models for classification?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, machine-learning, classification

I am reading multiple csv files and loading their information into pandas dataframe. I am trying to classify each file as being label `0` or label `1` from the target column, and each file has features with multiple values. I am having a bit of trouble finding the best approach to building a structure that can be properly processed using SVM classification model with `sklearn`

example dataframe:
[image example of the dataframe structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNNDz.png)

```
file  [1st feature] -  [2nd feature] -  [target]

0 -   [20,30,10...]  -  [0,1,2,3,4]  -   0

1 -   [10,50,20...] - [1,2,0,4,3]  -     1

2 -   [20,30,40...] - [2,4,0,1,3]  -     1

3 -   [50,10,40...] - [0,1,2,3,4]  -     1
```

Example Code I used to read the csv files into the dataframe:

```
    os.chdir("E:\Research Machine Learning\ComputerDebugging\option1")
    extension = 'csv'
    all_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

    #new DataFrame
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["%CPU","PID",'TimeStamp','target'])

    fields=["%CPU","PID",'TimeStamp']


    for f in all_files:
        files.append(f)
        bugs = pd.read_csv(f, header=0,usecols=fields,nrows=1800)
        bugs.sort_values(by=['TimeStamp','PID'], inplace=True)
        CPU =np.array( bugs["%CPU"])
        PID =np.array( bugs["PID"])
        df1.loc[f,'%CPU'] =  CPU
        df1.loc[f,'PID']= PID

    df1['target']=1
    print("Option 1:")
    print(df1.head(3),'\n')
```

I update the dataframe with the known target, as this is my training set. I do the same when reading files with label '0'.
Since each file needs its own classification I thought this might be the best way to do it, but I think I'm wrong.

I keep getting this error when I try to compile

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I believe it has to do with the fact that the model expects a single value, but its getting an array. Is there a way for a model to handle data with this structure. Or are there ways I can restructure this and retain the information?

Comment: Can you provide the code used to load the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I will edit with sample code.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you are having an issue because you are letting the default type get inferred.

> from the [pandas dataframe doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):
>
> dtype : dtype, default None Data type
> to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer

Try setting your df type to object when you define your df.

```
#new DataFrame
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["%CPU","PID",'TimeStamp','target'], dtype=object)
```